# Fabric sudo -u asks for password even though same command through shell session does not

Tags: ssh, fabric

Note I am not talking about SSH connections, but the `sudo -u` command once fabric has already established a connection as the `yuji` user.

```
run('whoami')  # outputs yuji
run('sudo -u postgres')  # pw prompt
run('sudo su postgres')  # pw prompt
sudo('ls', user='postgres')  # pw prompt
```

Causes a password prompt

```
[sudo] password for yuji:
```

If I SSH into the server manually, I can run the following commands without any problems.

```
ssh yuji@example.com
whoami  # yuji
sudo -u postgres  # no pw prompt
sudo su postgres  # no pw prompt
```

I'm curious what the difference is in the fabric environment?

My sudoers file

```
yuji ALL=(postgres) ALL
```